# Query path optimization and determining the best path programatically

Tags: mysql

I have created two graphs from the output of the EXPLAIN command for two queries.

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

The graph on top represents a query plan for the optimized query (joins). The graph on the bottom is unoptimized and uses correlated subqueries. Both queries return the same result set, I have just rewritten the correlated subquery into a join form.

Is there a calculation based on the number of edges / vertices that I can apply to these graphs to mathematically/programmatically prove that one query is better than the other.

I can accomplish determining which one is quicker by the execution time, but I was hoping that something could be inferred from the graph, or even the output of the EXPLAIN command in table form, perhaps the number of rows that have to be processed etc?

I want to build an algorithm to actually prove a query is better/faster (in addition to speed of the query) and not just subjective/opinion.

Comment: It sounds like you want to outsmart query optimizer

Comment: @lad2025, no, that's not accurate at all, im asking if there is a way to prove that one query is better than another by only looking at the graph or the explain output....